# Button Unlock is greyed at the settings users on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: settings, ubuntu-20.04

Button "Unlock" of screen Setting > Users does not work the click, it is greyed, why? I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly in my case I solved by doing this:

```
sudo apt-get remove chrome-remote-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Restart you computer (Needed)